# printf-style string formatting

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

Write a function that implements C `printf`-style string formatting.

## Rules

1. You **must** implement at least `%%`, `%c`, `%s`, `%d` and `%f`.
2. You **must not** use a built-in string formatting method.
3. You **must not** run external programs or connect to the Internet from your program.
4. It's up to you to decide how to handle invalid input, but your program **must not** terminate abnormally.
5. You **should** write a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) if possible.

> The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL NOT", "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED",  "MAY", and "OPTIONAL" in this document are to be interpreted as described in [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119).

Comment: What does `%c` do? Pretty sure `%s`, `%d` and `%f` are for strings, ints and floats respectivelly, but unsure about `%c`.

Comment: `%c` displays the ASCII value of a passed-in int IIRC

Comment: It prints the character, so `97` and `'a'` would both become `a` on the output.

Comment: no need to support some form like `%-02d` right? just that three %c, %s, %d?

Comment: @YOU Correct. That's enough.

Comment: I presume that it's necessary to handle `%%` too? What about unsupported `%<char>`: should that give an error, treat it as a literal `%`, or is the choice up to the implementer?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, I've clarified the instructions.

Comment: No build in language feature? What about using the build in `if` "feature"?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks for noticing, I'll clarify that, as I'm already on clarifying the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### APL (73)

```
{⊃,/,⌿↑(⊂2∘↓¨Z⊂G),⊂{'c'0≡⍵,∊⊃⍺:⎕UCS⍺⋄⍕⍺}/⍵,⍪⌷∘G¨1↓1+(Z←G='%')/⍳⍴G←'%!',⍺}
```

Some tests:

```
      'a:%c b:%s c:%d'{⊃,/,⌿↑(⊂2∘↓¨Z⊂G),⊂{'c'0≡⍵,∊⊃⍺:⎕UCS⍺⋄⍕⍺}/⍵,⍪⌷∘G¨1↓1+(Z←G='%')/⍳⍴G←'%!',⍺} 65 'foo' 67
a:A b:foo c:67 

      printf←{⊃,/,⌿↑(⊂2∘↓¨Z⊂G),⊂{'c'0≡⍵,∊⊃⍺:⎕UCS⍺⋄⍕⍺}/⍵,⍪⌷∘G¨1↓1+(Z←G='%')/⍳⍴G←'%!',⍺}
      '1:%s 2:%s 3:%d 4:%c 5:%c' printf 'foo' 'bar' 100 110 'z'
1:foo 2:bar 3:100 4:n 5:z   
      'The %s brown %c%c%c jumps over the %s dog.' printf 'quick' 102 111 'x' 'lazy'
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Explanation:

- `G←'%!',⍺`: prefix a dummy specifier to the string (for easier processing)
- `(Z←G='%')/⍳⍴G`: find the indices of all the `%` characters in the string; also store a bitmask in `Z`
- `⌷∘G¨1↓1+`: select all the characters next to the `%`s, and drop the dummy.
- `⍵,⍪`: match up each specifier with its value from the right argument.
- `{`...`}/`: run the following function on each pair:

  - `'c'0≡⍵,∊⊃⍺`: if the argument is a number and the specifier is `c`:
  - `:⎕UCS⍺`: then return the unicode value of the argument,
  - `⋄⍕⍺`: otherwise, return the string representation of the argument.
- `⊂`: enclose
- `⊂2∘↓¨Z⊂G`: split the string on the `%`s and then remove the first two characters of each substring (this is where the dummy comes in), and enclose the result of that.
- `↑`: make a matrix out of the two enclosed arrays, matching up each substring with the value that should follow it.
- `,⌿`: join each substring with its value.
- `⊃,/`: then join the resulting strings.

Comment: It's always fun to see esoteric languages that look like gibberish. ;)

Comment: @nyuszika7h: This is actually a serious language. It dates from the 1960s and it is still in use. It would look a bit less like gibberish if it wasn't golfed.

Comment: I see, interesting.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Well, technically it's list oriented programming language, so you could say it's designed for code golf, especially considering it uses a special character set intended to make programs more readable, and less verbose. And it was an inspiration for [J programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29) and GolfScript.

Comment: @xfix I thought LISP was the list oriented programming language?  We used APL in university for real work - being able to handle arrays natively is really handy.  J was designed by one of the inventers of APL as its "successor"  - of course that doesn't mean that it isn't useful for code golf...

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.2, 115 bytes

```
-- Function definition, 115 chars
function f(f,...)n,t=0,{...}return(f:gsub('%%(%a)',function(s)n=n+1return(({c=s.char})[s]or tostring)(t[n])end))end

-- Usage example
print(f('Happy %cew %d %s %f',78,2014,'Year!',math.pi))
-- Output: Happy New 2014 Year! 3.1415926535898
```

Comment: Nice one. Which version of Lua? 5.1.5 gives “malformed number near '1return'”. Small problem with “%c”, it fails on 'N' instead of 78. Or is it also just my old Lua's peculiarity?

Comment: @manatwork - Try [here](http://www.lua.org/demo.html)

Comment: Yepp, works there.

Comment: Works for me on Lua 5.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby: 102 characters

```ruby
f=->s,*a{s.gsub(/%(.)/){$1==?%??%:a.shift.send({?c=>:chr,?s=>:to_s,?d=>:to_i,?f=>:to_f}[$1])rescue$&}}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> f=->s,*a{s.gsub(/%(.)/){$1==?%??%:a.shift.send({?c=>:chr,?s=>:to_s,?d=>:to_i,?f=>:to_f}[$1])rescue$&}}
=> #<Proc:0x96634ac@(irb):1 (lambda)>

irb(main):002:0> puts f["percent : %%\n   char : %c or %c\n string : %s or %s or %s\ndecimal : %d or %d or %d\n  float : %f or %f or %f\ninvalid : %x or %s or %d or %f", 65, 'B', 'format me', 42, Math::PI, 42, Math::PI, '2014', 42, Math::PI, '2014', 'more']
percent : %
   char : A or B
 string : format me or 42 or 3.141592653589793
decimal : 42 or 3 or 2014
  float : 42.0 or 3.141592653589793 or 2014.0
invalid : %x or  or 0 or 0.0
=> nil
```

Invalid format specifiers are kept in place. Format specifiers without argument value are replaced with the empty value of the given type.

Comment: You can supply an anonymous function, so drop the leading `f`

Comment: Indeed. But as I remember, at the time of posting this, anonymous functions were not unanimously accepted. As for now neither the Lua answer was updated to anonymous function (to save the same amount of characters), I think I will not start the update campaign.

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (281 characters)

```
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdarg>
#define q(x)va_arg(v,x);break;case
std::string p(char*f,...){std::ostringstream r;va_list v;va_start(v,f);while(*f)if(*f=='%')switch(++f,*f++){case's':r<<q(char*)'d':r<<q(int)'c':r<<(char)q(int)'%':r<<'%';}else r<<*f++;va_end(v);return r.str();}
```

I hate C++, but it seemed like a good choice (I really would go with C, if not that `char*` pointer requires too much effort to be actually useful). Takes `char*` arguments, and `std::string` result, but hey, that's C++, so who cares about consistency (in language that itself isn't consistent)?

Comment: This doesn't compile, as it doesn't have a main function.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: The question was about making a function, not `main`. But if you need sample `main`, try https://gist.github.com/xfix/8238576 (I used that one while testing this function).

Comment: True, you can't really make a meaningful `main` function, adding one would just increase the character count. If I didn't want to modify the code, I could add an accompanying header file and `#include` it from my test program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>201</s> <s>186</s> 174 bytes

12 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```java
String f(String s,Object...a){String r="";for(char c,i=0,j=0;i<s.length();r+=c==37?(c=s.charAt(i++))<38?c:c==99?(char)(int)a[j++]:a[j++]:c==37?"":c)c=s.charAt(i++);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#XY/BasMwEETP9VeoAoGEhXCbQhI7wvTWHkILOZWQg6LItowjG2ndEoK/3XUTn3qaZWZn2df1x8ZqpBsVAtoq667jDrx1JSroPAT@cayNBiGEYtfZ9BLjrGg91ZXySHMrE17LJLObIBrjSqgoy3wstZSLZU61DOJv8xWojWPGNotVrtMpXK/z2wlGrQOm9nUcH9JZ7l2MU83@9TNvoPcO@WwYuztBAAWTfLf2hM4Tx/z9/qB8Gdg1ethdApizaHsQ3ZRA46gzPzdmykRB8ZvqugsiejLJCZGACCEF5ssVf06eXjj@Mso/Yr5VUInPd8ayaIiG8Rc)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can remove `=s.charAt(0)` from `char c=s.charAt(0)`. [It still works in the TIO when I do so.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jY8xa8MwEIXn5leoAoGEhXCbQhw7wnRrh9BCupSQQVFkW8ZRjHRpCca/PXUTT5kyvePefY977XHbWI10o0JAS2Vdd16Bt65EBR2HwD@2tdEghFCsG5deYpwVB091pTzS3MqY1zLO7CKIxrgSKsoyH0kt5XSWUy2D@L98BWqjiLHFNMl1OpjzeX6JYNQ6YGpdR9EmHeXKYpxqdsNn3sDRO@Sz/txeGwRQMMjPwe7Qfugxfr/eKF8G1k0eVqcAZi8ORxDt4EDjqDO/l86UiYLiN9W2J0T0sCQ7RAIihBSYzxL@HD@9cPxtlH/EfKmgEp/vjGV3ZA5BXyYA5klyJ0BukH7Sn/8A)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I swear that's quite clever.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can save 8 more bytes by printing directly: [`void f(String s,Object...a){for(char c,i=0,j=0;i<s.length();System.out.print(c==37?(c=s.charAt(i++))<38?c:c==99?(char)(int)a[j++]:a[j++]:c==37?"":c))c=s.charAt(i++);}` **166 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yc4nvds8) (and some more by converting to Java 8, but that's not really your thing, is it?)